# Bootstrap Table Alignment issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, alignment

I am trying to align my table header and  as shown on the picture, but so far I was unable to reach the desired outcome. I would like to have my header aligned to the right and the rest of the content to be aligned to the left side of the header. Is there any way to do this using **pure CSS** and **without manually specifying the offset**?

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="text-uppercase">
      <th>
        <h4>BlaBla</h4>
      </th>
      <th class="text-right">
        <h4>BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla</h4>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td class="text-right">Table cell</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td class="text-left">Table cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td><span style="position:relative; color: red; left: 185px;">Desired</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: table cell]

Comment: Please supply the code you've written thus far, so we have a better idea of your approach and the problems you're facing.

Comment: Here is a little fiddle containing the basic Bootstrap Table layout: https://jsfiddle.net/wakyLgzm/

Comment: It'd be great if you could add your code to the question itself, since questions shouldn't be overly reliant on external resources. Additionally, how does you current approach fail to achieve what you want? It's not immediately clear, I see some text is aligned to the right...(Edit this as more information into your question as well.)

Comment: I don't want to specify the indentation manually, as the website I am working on is multi-lingual, so the width of the header might vary. If there's no easy workaround this problem, then I guess I have to specify it by hand :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align the left edge of your `<span>` to the right of its parent element, but don't want to hard-code the required `left` offset to a pixel value, you can use a percentage value instead.

A percentage value for `left` will be relative to the `<span>`'s container's width, which will correspond to the length of the header. In this case you'd want `left:100%` (offset to the left by 100% of the container's width, aka. Pushed completely to the right of the container).

This CSS will work regardless of the length of the header (and by extension, the width of the `<span>`'s container), since it uses a relative rather than fixed value for the offset:

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="text-uppercase">
      <th>
        <h4>BlaBla</h4>
      </th>
      <th class="text-right">
        <h4>BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla</h4>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td class="text-right">Table cell</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td class="text-left">Table cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td><span style="position:relative; color: red; left: 100%">Desired</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.